# Validation of integer inout and in general

Tags: c

How would I validate that the user enters a correct input, e.g. for an integer, since I am declaring the variables as ints before. (Meaning alpha would get numerical inputs.)
Also, is there a more general way of validating inputs and getting inputs; other than using scanf?

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main() {
    printf("We will check if your number is odd, even, zero or negative \n");
    int input;
    printf("Enter your number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (input < 0){
        printf("Number is Negative \n");
    }
    else if (input == 0){
        printf("Number is Zero \n");
    }
    else if (input % 2 == 0){
         printf("Number is Even \n");
    }
    else if (input % 2 == 1){
        printf("Number is Odd \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could start by checking what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*. Then continue by [reading a full line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead and use a [conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which allows you to do more thorough validation of the input.

Comment: Or if you would like to take multiple integer inputs per-line, then, in the event of a *matching* failure, you will need to discard characters in the input buffer until the next digit is found, or a `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered. (`ungetc` a digit if found at the end of discarding extraneous characters) The key to using `scanf` in any sane manner is checking the **return** and acting accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `scanf()` family implies that the input is expected in perfect syntax for the conversion specifier given (in this case "%d" -> integer).
If you instead want to verify that correctness of the syntax of the input, then you need to take the input as a whole and then parse it yourself.
You can use e.g. `fgets()` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to do so.

Once you have the input saved in a "string" (chars in an array or allocated memory), you can start "guessing" at what it is, using multiple `sscanf()` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). This is much easier on a string which is already in memory than on the input stream. Because "wrong guess after partial success, try again from start" is easy in memory but hard on input.

As SomeProgrammerDude has already commented, the way to attempt scanning with  `sscanf()` (in memory, or `scanf()` on input) is to check the return value; it will tell you about success or failure.